# Linux Perl - A Script printing its script name?

Tags: linux, perl

I am running a script named **statusCron.pl**.

I want when I run that script, that script can detect/print its name which is **statusCron.pl**. By that I can detect its process ID so that if it found itself already running on the background it will kill itself.

By this I can eliminate hardcoding and re-apply it to all of my scripts.

[Additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712199/linux-perl-a-script-printing-its-script-name#comment-45712415): I dont want the directory to be included.

Comment: Additional: I dont want the directory to be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of running program in `$0` variable and to avoid the directory name we use the module File::Basename to get only the basename.

```
    use File::Basename;
    my $name = basename($0);
    print $name;
```

[man perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for other special variables

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added information. It really helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use File::Basename like this:

```
use File::Basename;
print basename(__FILE__), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print both the name of the Perl script file and the process ID by writing this

```
printf("%s %d\n", $0 =~ m|([^\\/]+)$|, $$);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, additional useful information. I might use this in the future.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $0;
```

`$0` stores the name of the script